# Which pattern and how to structure this [Different serviceHandlers, structure and validation]?

Tags: php, codeigniter, design-patterns

Alright so I'm trying to make some sense of all these patterns.

Alright, so I'm coding an applicantion in CodeIgniter which needs to be able to send data about a car and a customer to different types of companies using SOAP, maybe XML, comma-separated and so on.

But they all need the same thing.

I wanna make it as dynamic as possible and make sure it's easy to write tests.

So the service should take a couple of things:

- a handler
- applicants [1-2]
- params
- object

I started up creating different classes

Gr8Exp
NordCar
SwePerf

each implementing the interface **iServiceRequest**

```
interface iServiceRequest{
    /**
     * Send the request to the company server.
     */
    function sendRequest();
    /**
     * Saves the response into the database.
     */
    function saveResponse();
    /**
     * Prepares the request to the company, setting info from form and shit.
     */
    function prepareRequest();
    /**
     * Soap, XML, CSV, JSON
     * @param type $method
     */
    function setRequestHandler(iServiceRequestHandler $handler);
}
```

Then they need to structure up the Soap, XML, CSV, JSON request depending on what handler i put in.

After those who needed to be validated (not all did) I used:

```
interface iAdaptServiceRequest{
    /**
     * Structure the array information and put it into an object structure in the right place.
    */
    function structure(array $info);
    /**
     * Make all the checks for the function
     */
    function validateInfo();
}
```

But I'm stuck, It worked really good when I just used SOAP request; but now. Since I need to format them differently, use a different handler for each type of request or company I don't know what to do.
I could put them i different folders and recreate the class in the different folders. But that's not a good practice since I'm duplicating code all over.

In the end I want to run some chaining like this:

$result = $m->prepareRequest()->sendRequest()->saveResponse();

Any suggestions??

Comment: Use something like ->setType('json') ..etc then make your request handler use this to structure the data.

Comment: You'll have to normalize your data, making it easy to output any structure you want, then based on requested type you pass the data to a handler that will format the data & return it, it would be much easier than duplicating your files + it will allow you to add more in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO:

-- create/use a front controller.

-- The front controller determines which request handler to use (JSON, SOAP, XML, etc).

-- The request handler generates a common "Request" object that behaves the same across all interfaces, basically putting variables into a common named format inside a "Request object"

-- It determines which service to send the request to and sends the request object there

-- The service processes the request object and generates a response object

-- The controller creates an appropriate (JSON/SOAP/XML) View object to process the response object into the correct view type and the View outputs your response as that type.

Comment: Alright, I've done it like this now. But I've plenty of assignments in my controller now. Not much cases.

Like this:

$object->setRegistrationNumber($regNr).

I've heard it should be a clean controller. As I understand the MVC pattern in CI is not really an MVC anyway.

Should I move the assignments into a model, then do the exact same thing? Or can I keep them in the controller. I know it works anyhow. but I want it to have a "proper"-structure.

I'll wait a few days and watch for replies, then I'll accept your answer later if no better is coming up. I think this answers my question.

Comment: The controller is providing control code. some of that is moving variable into your models. that is fine. however, if during the setting of a variable it needs to be multiplied by 50, that should go in the model. Basically anything related to that model data set that needs to happen repeatedly to it should go in the model.

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like yours: `$result = $m->prepareRequest('JSON')->sendRequest()->saveResponse();`, but specifing what format of data I'm sending.

The method `prepareRequest(string $type)` would check the format and call another method to convert your data to the respective format.

Something like this:

```
function prepareRequest(string $type){
     if ($type == 'json'){
          $this->convert2json();
     }
     if ($type == 'xml'){
          $this->convert2xml();
     }
     // And so on
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is often confusion about the MVC or Observer pattern. This is not a situation in which this pattern is applicable. In the MVC pattern are the View and Model related to one another. The View must update itself based on information of the subject. A view and the underlying tables in a database are a good example. That is not what you want here.

The design pattern which suits this problem is the Builder pattern. The Builder pattern consists of four cooperating classtypes:
1. a Builder,
2. a ReaderManager,
3. a ConverterManager, and
4. a DataObject.
The ReaderManager is using the Interpreter pattern. Conversion can be done using the State pattern. What is the output of the ReaderManager (some DataObject) is the input for the ConversionManager. That can be done using an abstract class instead of an interface (my preference for data focused classes). The Builder connects the ReaderManager with the ConverterManager and takes care of the transport of data.

Some years ago I wrote about design patterns. The builder pattern was one of the patterns I described and this is the link to that page:
http://www.loekbergman.nl/InsideArchitecture/TheProcess/DesignPatterns/Builder
It shows a UML diagram of the pattern. 
In the next link you can download a jar with some examples of design patterns. One of them the builder pattern:
http://www.loekbergman.nl/InsideArchitecture/DownloadsAndLicense
I have written this code several years ago, therefor do I give you this code without warranty. (Is that the correct term in this context?)
In the code you can see a folder with the name specifications. That is another example of the Interpreter pattern. (In the Builder pattern there is of course also an example of this pattern).

To be complete is here the link to the MVC - pattern:
http://www.loekbergman.nl/InsideArchitecture/TheProcess/DesignPatterns/Observer
and the Interpreter pattern:
http://www.loekbergman.nl/InsideArchitecture/TheProcess/DesignPatterns/Interpreter